# How to filter for only unique errors in multiple logs using grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, logs, date

I am trying to use the following pattern on Ubuntu:

```
grep -Eri "warning|error|critical|severe|fatal" --color=auto
```

to find relevant errors in many different .log files recursively in /var/log and its subfolders.

The issue I am having is that this results in tens of thousands of lines of matches being printed as the expression is run. I'd like to filter these somehow in at least one of the following ways:

1. Print but then skip a match if more than eg. 3 of the same match exist
2. Show only unique matches (i.e. print one of each line found)

Can I do this by piping the output to something? Currently going through each log for errors is incredibly time consuming which is why I am trying this. But the expression I am using prints so much info that it is also not usable itself either. I have tried piping to 'less' but that removes highlighting which makes it harder to read and does not fix the issue with the output being so large.

I realise I could also limit the expression to specific files at a time, but as I mentioned some logs are full of matches and others have very little. So further filtering out duplicates would be really helpful.

Here is an example error line in one of the many logs I am searching:

```
./artifactory/artifactory-service.log:20:2021-07-20T08:45:30.248Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [.j.a.c.g.GrpcStreamObserver:97] [c-default-executor-1] - refreshing affected platform config stream - got an error
```

If there are hundreds of such errors, I would like to show eg. at most 3 of these before moving onto the next match.

Alternatively, due to how the dates are listed in the log. It would be great to filter to match for only specific dates, how would I go about doing this? Date filtering would limit the output greatly.

Comment: Yes, you can pipe to something, but we can't really help without an example. Will the lines be 100% identical? Should we only consider certain fields? Certain characters? Do you also want to include the file name? Does that affect what is considered a duplicate? Should the same error message in two different files be treated as the same error or a separate one? Please [edit] your question and add an example input (input here being the result of your grep, or alternatively a set of input files) and show us what your desired output from that input would be. Also mention your OS, pelase.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I've updated the question with the information you requested. I would like to include the file name yes. I've just started using eg. `find . -name '*.log' -exec grep -Ein 'warning|warn|error|critical|severe|fatal' --color=auto {} +` but it does not help with limiting the scope to specific matching dates, as I am unsure how to include that in the search string.

Comment: Cut off everything that contains changing values (timestamps, connection IDs) and pipe that to `sort | uniq`

Comment: Hi Panki, could you please give an example using the log I provided?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I'm afraid a single line doesn't tell us much since you are specifically talking about "duplicates". Will there be multiple _identical_ lines in the same file? Will there be similar lines with maybe a different timestpamp? Would those be duplicates? Your output also includes the line number, if that changes (as it will), does it mean they are not duplicates? Remember, _you_ know what you need, but we don't and we need to explain it to a computer, so it has to be very clear. Can you give us a few lines, some of which are dupes and some not so we can udnerstand?

Comment: By the way, you can use `--color=always` and pipe to `less -R` to presever the highlighting: `find . -name '*.log' -exec grep -Ein 'warning|warn|error|critical|severe|fatal' --color=always {} + | less -R`.

Comment: Read `man journalctl` and the `journalctl` hints in my StackExchange profile - click on my username and select the Profile tab